# WebSphere JAX-WS: JAXBException class is not known to this context

Tags: java, web-services, jaxb, websphere, jax-ws

I'm trying to deploy a JAX-WS service client onto a WebSphere v8.5.5 app server, and use it to call a SOAP service that's deployed in a different server. I've finally resolved all of the security issues and it's making a successful request, but when it gets to the point of translating the response back to JAXB objects, it throws Context issues that it can't find the appropriate class.

```
[1/20/17 16:21:56:131 EST] 000001aa JAXBUtils     3 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils getJAXBContext new JAXBContext constructed, elapsed time msec: 1934
[1/20/17 16:21:56:131 EST] 000001aa JAXBUtils     1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils getJAXBContext JAXBContext [created or retrieved from hard map] for [@preference.v1, @preference.v1_0.commonheadertypes, @preference.v1_0.filterheader, @preference.v1_0.filterheaderresponse, @preference.v1_0.getfilterheaderrequest, @preference.v1_0.getpreferencesrequest, @preference.v1_0.getpreferencesresponse, @preference.v1_0.isaliveresponse, @preference.v1_0.preference, @preference.v1_0.setpreferencesrequest, @preference.v1_0.setpreferencesresponse, [preference.v1.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.commonheadertypes.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.commonheadertypes.RequestHeader], [preference.v1_0.filterheader.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.filterheaderresponse.FilterHeaderResponse], [preference.v1_0.filterheaderresponse.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.getfilterheaderrequest.GetFilterHeaderRequest], [preference.v1_0.getfilterheaderrequest.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.getpreferencesrequest.GetPreferencesRequest], [preference.v1_0.getpreferencesrequest.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.getpreferencesresponse.GetPreferencesResponse], [preference.v1_0.getpreferencesresponse.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.isaliveresponse.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.isaliveresponse.Response], [preference.v1_0.preference.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.setpreferencesrequest.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.setpreferencesrequest.SetPreferencesRequest], [preference.v1_0.setpreferencesresponse.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.setpreferencesresponse.SetPreferencesResponse], preference.v1, preference.v1.0.commonheadertypes, preference.v1.0.filterheader, preference.v1.0.filterheaderresponse, preference.v1.0.getfilterheaderrequest, preference.v1.0.getpreferencesrequest, preference.v1.0.getpreferencesresponse, preference.v1.0.isaliverequest, preference.v1.0.isaliveresponse, preference.v1.0.preference, preference.v1.0.setpreferencesrequest, preference.v1.0.setpreferencesresponse, preference.v1_0.commonheadertypes, preference.v1_0.commonheadertypes > preference.v1.0.commonheadertypes, preference.v1_0.filterheader, preference.v1_0.filterheaderresponse, preference.v1_0.getfilterheaderrequest, preference.v1_0.getfilterheaderrequest > preference.v1.0.getfilterheaderrequest, preference.v1_0.getpreferencesrequest, preference.v1_0.getpreferencesrequest > preference.v1.0.getpreferencesrequest, preference.v1_0.getpreferencesresponse, preference.v1_0.isaliveresponse, preference.v1_0.preference, preference.v1_0.setpreferencesrequest, preference.v1_0.setpreferencesrequest > preference.v1.0.setpreferencesrequest, preference.v1_0.setpreferencesresponse, preferences.v1]
[1/20/17 16:21:56:132 EST] 000001aa JAXBUtils     1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils getJAXBContext JAXBContext also stored by the list of valid packages:[]
[1/20/17 16:21:56:132 EST] 000001aa JAXBUtils     1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils getJAXBContext JAXBContext constructionType= BY_CLASS_ARRAY_PLUS_ARRAYS
[1/20/17 16:21:56:133 EST] 000001aa JAXBUtils     1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils getJAXBContext JAXBContextValue = org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils$JAXBContextValue@1b35cebd
[1/20/17 16:21:56:133 EST] 000001aa JAXBUtils     1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils getJAXBContext JAXBContext = com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.JAXBContextImpl@b2008b5b
[1/20/17 16:21:56:134 EST] 000001aa JAXBUtils     3 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils getJAXBContext JAXBContextCreate: creation completed
[1/20/17 16:21:56:134 EST] 000001aa JAXBUtils     1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils getJAXBUnmarshaller Unmarshaller created [not in pool]
[1/20/17 16:21:56:152 EST] 000001aa DocLitWrapped 1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.marshaller.impl.alt.DocLitWrappedMinimalMethodMarshaller demarshalResponse fail demarshalResponse e=org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: preference.v1_0.filterheaderresponse.FilterHeaderResponse is not known to this context
[1/20/17 16:21:56:156 EST] 000001aa ExceptionFact 1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.ExceptionFactory logRootCause Root Cause:javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: preference.v1_0.filterheaderresponse.FilterHeaderResponse is not known to this context
```

If I look at the whole stack trace, I can see that the context even retrieves all of the objects from the hard map. Additionally, it's thinking that it needs to create a new JAXBContext, even though one was already created for the request that worked fine. Below is the trace from when it constructed the context for the request, where it did find the appropriate packages.

```
[1/20/17 16:21:51:959 EST] 000001aa JAXBUtils     3 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils getJAXBContext new JAXBContext constructed, elapsed time msec: 1369
[1/20/17 16:21:51:960 EST] 000001aa JAXBUtils     1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils getJAXBContext jaxbMap.put3, validPackagesKey[[preference.v1, preference.v1_0.commonheadertypes, preference.v1_0.filterheader, preference.v1_0.filterheaderresponse, preference.v1_0.getfilterheaderrequest, preference.v1_0.getpreferencesrequest, preference.v1_0.getpreferencesresponse, preference.v1_0.isaliveresponse, preference.v1_0.preference, preference.v1_0.setpreferencesrequest, preference.v1_0.setpreferencesresponse]]  softRef2[java.lang.ref.SoftReference@b0f234e3]
[1/20/17 16:21:51:960 EST] 000001aa JAXBUtils     1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils getJAXBContext JAXBContext [created or retrieved from hard map] for [@preference.v1, @preference.v1_0.commonheadertypes, @preference.v1_0.filterheader, @preference.v1_0.filterheaderresponse, @preference.v1_0.getfilterheaderrequest, @preference.v1_0.getpreferencesrequest, @preference.v1_0.getpreferencesresponse, @preference.v1_0.isaliveresponse, @preference.v1_0.preference, @preference.v1_0.setpreferencesrequest, @preference.v1_0.setpreferencesresponse, [preference.v1.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.commonheadertypes.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.commonheadertypes.RequestHeader], [preference.v1_0.filterheader.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.filterheaderresponse.FilterHeaderResponse], [preference.v1_0.filterheaderresponse.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.getfilterheaderrequest.GetFilterHeaderRequest], [preference.v1_0.getfilterheaderrequest.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.getpreferencesrequest.GetPreferencesRequest], [preference.v1_0.getpreferencesrequest.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.getpreferencesresponse.GetPreferencesResponse], [preference.v1_0.getpreferencesresponse.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.isaliveresponse.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.isaliveresponse.Response], [preference.v1_0.preference.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.setpreferencesrequest.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.setpreferencesrequest.SetPreferencesRequest], [preference.v1_0.setpreferencesresponse.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.setpreferencesresponse.SetPreferencesResponse], preference.v1, preference.v1.0.commonheadertypes, preference.v1.0.filterheader, preference.v1.0.filterheaderresponse, preference.v1.0.getfilterheaderrequest, preference.v1.0.getpreferencesrequest, preference.v1.0.getpreferencesresponse, preference.v1.0.isaliverequest, preference.v1.0.isaliveresponse, preference.v1.0.preference, preference.v1.0.setpreferencesrequest, preference.v1.0.setpreferencesresponse, preference.v1_0.commonheadertypes, preference.v1_0.commonheadertypes > preference.v1.0.commonheadertypes, preference.v1_0.filterheader, preference.v1_0.filterheaderresponse, preference.v1_0.getfilterheaderrequest, preference.v1_0.getfilterheaderrequest > preference.v1.0.getfilterheaderrequest, preference.v1_0.getpreferencesrequest, preference.v1_0.getpreferencesrequest > preference.v1.0.getpreferencesrequest, preference.v1_0.getpreferencesresponse, preference.v1_0.isaliveresponse, preference.v1_0.preference, preference.v1_0.setpreferencesrequest, preference.v1_0.setpreferencesrequest > preference.v1.0.setpreferencesrequest, preference.v1_0.setpreferencesresponse, preferences.v1]
[1/20/17 16:21:51:961 EST] 000001aa JAXBUtils     1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils getJAXBContext JAXBContext also stored by the list of valid packages:[preference.v1, preference.v1_0.commonheadertypes, preference.v1_0.filterheader, preference.v1_0.filterheaderresponse, preference.v1_0.getfilterheaderrequest, preference.v1_0.getpreferencesrequest, preference.v1_0.getpreferencesresponse, preference.v1_0.isaliveresponse, preference.v1_0.preference, preference.v1_0.setpreferencesrequest, preference.v1_0.setpreferencesresponse]
[1/20/17 16:21:51:961 EST] 000001aa JAXBUtils     1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils getJAXBContext JAXBContext constructionType= BY_CONTEXT_PATH
[1/20/17 16:21:51:962 EST] 000001aa JAXBUtils     1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils getJAXBContext JAXBContextValue = org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils$JAXBContextValue@231f9d4e
[1/20/17 16:21:51:962 EST] 000001aa JAXBUtils     1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils getJAXBContext JAXBContext = com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.JAXBContextImpl@6914a4cd
[1/20/17 16:21:51:962 EST] 000001aa JAXBUtils     3 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils getJAXBContext JAXBContextCreate: creation completed
[1/20/17 16:21:51:963 EST] 000001aa JAXBUtils     1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils getJAXBMarshaller Marshaller created [not in pool]
[1/20/17 16:21:52:037 EST] 000001aa ContextUtils  1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.context.utils.ContextUtils _isJAXBRemoveIllegalChars isJAXBRemoveIllegalChars returns the default: false
[1/20/17 16:21:52:037 EST] 000001aa ContextUtils  1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.context.utils.ContextUtils getRelatedMessageContext Enter getRelatedMessageContext for:[MessageContext: logID=74ca574be105a3cab3233c4f8e1638f3fe4fbae7c632556e]
[1/20/17 16:21:52:038 EST] 000001aa ContextUtils  1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.context.utils.ContextUtils getRelatedMessageContext Exit getRelatedMessageContext related messageContext is[MessageContext: logID=64ca574be105a3cab3233c4f8e1638f3fe4fbae7c632556e]
[1/20/17 16:21:52:038 EST] 000001aa ContextUtils  1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.context.utils.ContextUtils _isJAXBRemoveIllegalChars isJAXBRemoveIllegalChars returns the default: false
[1/20/17 16:21:52:069 EST] 000001aa JAXBUtils     1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils releaseJAXBMarshaller Marshaller placed back into pool
[1/20/17 16:21:52:069 EST] 000001aa JAXBUtils     1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils releaseJAXBMarshaller   Marshaller = com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.marshal.MarshallerImpl@e4f59217
[1/20/17 16:21:52:070 EST] 000001aa JAXBUtils     1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils releaseJAXBMarshaller   JAXBContext = com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.JAXBContextImpl@6914a4cd
[1/20/17 16:21:52:070 EST] 000001aa BlockImpl     1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.BlockImpl outputTo End outputTo
[1/20/17 16:21:52:071 EST] 000001aa BlockImpl     1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.BlockImpl outputTo Start outputTo
[1/20/17 16:21:52:071 EST] 000001aa BlockImpl     1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.impl.BlockImpl outputTo Write business object
[1/20/17 16:21:52:072 EST] 000001aa JAXBUtils     1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils getJAXBContext key[[@preference.v1, @preference.v1_0.commonheadertypes, @preference.v1_0.filterheader, @preference.v1_0.filterheaderresponse, @preference.v1_0.getfilterheaderrequest, @preference.v1_0.getpreferencesrequest, @preference.v1_0.getpreferencesresponse, @preference.v1_0.isaliveresponse, @preference.v1_0.preference, @preference.v1_0.setpreferencesrequest, @preference.v1_0.setpreferencesresponse, [preference.v1.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.commonheadertypes.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.commonheadertypes.RequestHeader], [preference.v1_0.filterheader.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.filterheaderresponse.FilterHeaderResponse], [preference.v1_0.filterheaderresponse.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.getfilterheaderrequest.GetFilterHeaderRequest], [preference.v1_0.getfilterheaderrequest.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.getpreferencesrequest.GetPreferencesRequest], [preference.v1_0.getpreferencesrequest.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.getpreferencesresponse.GetPreferencesResponse], [preference.v1_0.getpreferencesresponse.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.isaliveresponse.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.isaliveresponse.Response], [preference.v1_0.preference.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.setpreferencesrequest.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.setpreferencesrequest.SetPreferencesRequest], [preference.v1_0.setpreferencesresponse.ObjectFactory], [preference.v1_0.setpreferencesresponse.SetPreferencesResponse], preference.v1, preference.v1.0.commonheadertypes, preference.v1.0.filterheader, preference.v1.0.filterheaderresponse, preference.v1.0.getfilterheaderrequest, preference.v1.0.getpreferencesrequest, preference.v1.0.getpreferencesresponse, preference.v1.0.isaliverequest, preference.v1.0.isaliveresponse, preference.v1.0.preference, preference.v1.0.setpreferencesrequest, preference.v1.0.setpreferencesresponse, preference.v1_0.commonheadertypes, preference.v1_0.commonheadertypes > preference.v1.0.commonheadertypes, preference.v1_0.filterheader, preference.v1_0.filterheaderresponse, preference.v1_0.getfilterheaderrequest, preference.v1_0.getfilterheaderrequest > preference.v1.0.getfilterheaderrequest, preference.v1_0.getpreferencesrequest, preference.v1_0.getpreferencesrequest > preference.v1.0.getpreferencesrequest, preference.v1_0.getpreferencesresponse, preference.v1_0.isaliveresponse, preference.v1_0.preference, preference.v1_0.setpreferencesrequest, preference.v1_0.setpreferencesrequest > preference.v1.0.setpreferencesrequest, preference.v1_0.setpreferencesresponse, preferences.v1]]
[1/20/17 16:21:52:072 EST] 000001aa JAXBUtils     1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils getJAXBContext Following packages are in this batch of getJAXBContext() :
[1/20/17 16:21:52:073 EST] 000001aa JAXBUtils     1 org.apache.axis2.jaxws.message.databinding.JAXBUtils getJAXBContext @preference.v1
```

I was researching a bit and found that improper JAXB tagging can be the issue, so below are the classes being used in this transaction. Let me know if I need to include any other classes.

Preference.java

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "Preference", targetNamespace = "http://someurl.com/preference/v1.0/", wsdlLocation = "/META-INF/wsdl/Preference.wsdl")
public class Preference
    extends Service
{
@WebEndpoint(name = "PreferenceSoap")
    public PreferenceSoap getPreferenceSoap() {
        return super.getPort(new QName("http://someurl.com/preference/v1.0/", "PreferenceSoap"), PreferenceSoap.class);
    }
}
```

PreferenceSoap.java

```
@WebService(name = "PreferenceSoap", targetNamespace = "http://someurl.com/preference/v1.0/")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    preference.v1.ObjectFactory.class,
    preference.v1_0.commonheadertypes.ObjectFactory.class,
    preference.v1_0.filterheader.ObjectFactory.class,
    preference.v1_0.filterheaderresponse.ObjectFactory.class,
    preference.v1_0.getfilterheaderrequest.ObjectFactory.class,
    preference.v1_0.getpreferencesrequest.ObjectFactory.class,
    preference.v1_0.getpreferencesresponse.ObjectFactory.class,
    preference.v1_0.isaliveresponse.ObjectFactory.class,
    preference.v1_0.preference.ObjectFactory.class,
    preference.v1_0.setpreferencesrequest.ObjectFactory.class,
    preference.v1_0.setpreferencesresponse.ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface PreferenceSoap {
    /**
     * 
     * @param getFilterHeaderRequest
     * @return
     *     returns preference.v1_0.filterheaderresponse.FilterHeaderResponse
     */
    @WebMethod(operationName = "GetFilterHeaders", action = "http://someurl.com/preference/v1.0/GetFilterHeaders")
    @WebResult(name = "GetFilterHeadersResult", targetNamespace = "http://someurl.com/preference/v1.0/")
    @RequestWrapper(localName = "GetFilterHeaders", targetNamespace = "http://someurl.com/preference/v1.0/", className = "preference.v1.GetFilterHeaders")
    @ResponseWrapper(localName = "GetFilterHeadersResponse", targetNamespace = "http://someurl.com/preference/v1.0/", className = "preference.v1.GetFilterHeadersResponse")
    public FilterHeaderResponse getFilterHeaders(
        @WebParam(name = "RequestHeader", targetNamespace = "http://someurl.com/preferences/v1.0/", header = true)
        RequestHeader requestHeader,
      @WebParam(name = "getFilterHeaderRequest", targetNamespace = "http://someurl.com/preference/v1.0/")
      GetFilterHeaderRequest getFilterHeaderRequest);
}
```

GetFilterHeadersResponse.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "getFilterHeadersResult"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "GetFilterHeadersResponse")
public class GetFilterHeadersResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "GetFilterHeadersResult")
    protected FilterHeaderResponse getFilterHeadersResult;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the getFilterHeadersResult property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link FilterHeaderResponse }
     *     
     */
    public FilterHeaderResponse getGetFilterHeadersResult() {
        return getFilterHeadersResult;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the getFilterHeadersResult property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link FilterHeaderResponse }
     *     
     */
    public void setGetFilterHeadersResult(FilterHeaderResponse value) {
        this.getFilterHeadersResult = value;
    }

}
```

filterheaderresponse.ObjectFactory.java

```
package preference.v1_0.filterheaderresponse;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {


    /**
     * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create new instances of schema derived classes for package: preference.v1_0.filterheaderresponse
     * 
     */
    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link FilterHeaderResponse }
     * 
     */
    public FilterHeaderResponse createFilterHeaderResponse() {
        return new FilterHeaderResponse();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link ArrayOfFilterHeader }
     * 
     */
    public ArrayOfFilterHeader createArrayOfFilterHeader() {
        return new ArrayOfFilterHeader();
    }

}
```

Is there something that I'm missing in all of this? When I run it locally against a generic IBM JAX-WS thin client, it works perfectly fine, so is there some additional configuration setting I need to make in WebSphere to get this to work? Also, why would it be able to construct an appropriate context for the request but not the response?

Comment: If wsimport ran without any warnings, you haven't altered or subclassed any of the generated code, and all the generated code is packaged in the app, then this would be a good candidate for IBM support.

Comment: Thanks. I'm still relatively new to Java (and especially JAX-WS) programming, so I wanted to make sure I wasn't doing anything wrong in the code before bringing it to IBM. I'll post the resolution once I get it from them in case anyone else runs into this same issue.

Comment: @lilweirdward hi, have you got the solution? i am facing same exception when arrays used for `@WebParam`

Comment: It's been a long time since I banged my head against the wall with this issue, so I don't remember much of the context with how I got this far, but unfortunately this was never resolved. IBM was never any help and I couldn't ever get this to run on the server. Sorry for the bad news :( hopefully you have better luck!

Answer (score 0):

Are both servers WAS 8.5.5 servers? Maybe it's a difference in the jaxblibrary versions? e.g., JAXB 2.1 vs 2.2?

Comment: This is a good thought and IBM suggested it as well, but both servers (local thin client + full dev server) are on v8.5.5 which runs on 2.2, and the code was generated with 2.2 based on the generated comments in the package-info classes.